Why does the TS compiler assume my value could be {}?
I have defined a simple ID type, and a type that should represent all suitable properties from a given object type that might hold this ID:
export type MyId = string | number;

export type MyIdProp<T extends object> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (MyId | undefined) ? K : never
}[keyof T];

I think this should be correct:
MyIdProp assumes, for a given object type T, an object type that maps properties of T to themselves, but only those properties whose value is assignable to MyId or undefined.
And then, only the properties listed in this assumed object are taken into account to form the resulting union.
Now, I'm trying to retrieve the ID value from a given object in a generic function:
function doSomething<T extends object>(obj: T, idAttr: MyIdProp<T>): MyId {
    const objId = obj[idAttr];
    if (objId === undefined || objId === null) {
        throw new Error('No ID supplied!');
    }

    return objId;
}

However, this fails with error 2322 on the line return objId;, saying:

Type 'T[MyIdProp] & {}' is not assignable to type 'MyId'.

Why? Where does that & {} come from and how do I prevent this?

This looks like an XY problem... do you really care about & {} or do you want your function to compile? The & {} just means it's not nullable, which is what you get when you check for being defined. Your actual problem is that TS has no native "KeysMatching" operator as requested in ms/TS#48992 so it doesn't "get" the T[KeysMatching<T, V>] is assignable to V. This is therefore essentially a duplicate of this q and the fix looks like this. Thoughts?

<T extends object> looks too broad. T could be { a: true } and would satisfy the generic but you would not be able to pass a 2nd parameter to it meaning the function doesn't work for the given generic constraint. & {} also means that "it's an object of some kind" which is the most TypeScript can tell you about T given that generic constraint
